# Only ping fail output should get visible

Tags: linux, ping, icmp

Is there a possibility for getting only the error output when running the `ping` command?  Its very tricky to understand if we have n number of server monitoring.

`icmp_seq` will obviously show the drop calculation by the missing numbers, but I need the RTO on the screen to monitor them. It is very difficult to monitor 4-5 sessions at a time.

It will continue to ping for more than 6 hrs for monitoring purposes.

Comment: `ping www.google.com | grep timeout` or `ping -c5  www.google.com` to do only 5 pings

Comment: I tried the `ping www.google.com | grep timeout` but it is not showing any output even after the host is down.

Comment: log output to a file

Comment: How about using `smokeping' instead? The output is much more interesting, is graphical, and it keeps history. Click into one of the router demos.  http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping-demo/?target=Customers.OP

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: We would have used `smokeping` but the setup will be in a different region or may be different customer. 
So this wont be possible. there should be something which will at-least show me some blank line to track

Comment: What about redirecting stdout? `ping -c5 bbc.co.uk > /dev/null` (returns nothing); `ping -c5 foo.bar.uk > /dev/null` (returns: `ping: cannot resolve foo.bar.uk: Unknown host`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to do this by the below command.

```
touch ping-result-data.txt; while true; do ping  -c 1 -w 2 192.168.56.11 || echo “`date` ping NG” >> ping-result-data.txt; sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ping -O server.example.com | grep -v --line-buffered '^64 bytes from'
```

Use `kill -INT` from another terminal to end the pinging if you want to see the final statistics.

Comment: Alexp Its not working...　ping -o doesn't exist.

Comment: It's `-O` not `-o`.

Comment: Still not working, I searched the man page there is nothing like that.

Comment: There are slightly different implementations of ping available on diferrent unix variants. I think -0 seems to work fine on Ubuntu, but not at all on OSX. I think the solution might be busybox... and if I get that to work I will return with a full answer...

Comment: Another version: `$ ping -O 1.1.1.1 | fgrep 'no answer yet' --line-buffered | ts`